# Can I declare a OnClickListener derived class and pass its instance to a view's setOnClickListener method in Frida

Tags: android, frida

In Frida's hooking javascript file,Can I declare a new class which is derived from OnClickListener? I want to pass a new OnClickListener instance to an existing view's setOnClickListener method.

I can get a existing view class as below:

```
var viewCls = Java.use("com.xxx.myView");
```

This view does not have any onClickListener in original app. Would it be possible to attach a onClickListener instance to this view through Frida?

I know how to instance an existing class but I do not know how to declare a new class in Frida.

Thanks so much for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find how to declare a new class in Frida. However, I found a workaround to get my requirement done. I share it here and hopefully can help those who met the same issue with me. Basically, what I want to do is to add a onClickListener for a existing View instance. Since we could not declare a new onClickListener derived class in Frida, we can declare it in a separate dex library file. In Frida, we can dynamic load this dex file, find the class, and  then new it .The step is as below:

1, Create a java library with your own onClickListener derived class declared. For example:

```
package com.test.frida
class MyOnClickListener implements onClickListener {
     public void onClick() {
         //you code here
     }
}
```

2, Compile it to a Android library file, which is assumed as mylib.dex. Then push it to android device.

3, In Frida, assuming the view you want to add onClickListener is appView. We first load mylib.dex as below:

```
var loader = Java.use("dalvik.system.DexClassLoader").$new(mylib_dex_path, optimizeDir, null, appView.getContext())
```

optimizeDir should be a directory belongs to the app. It is easy to find a one.

4, Get MyOnClickListener.class and new a instance for it.

```
Java.classFactory.loader = loader;
var myListenerCls = Java.classFactory.use("com.test.frida.MyOnClickListener");
var listenerObj = myListenerCls.$new();
```

5, Finally, pass this listener to appView

```
appView.setOnClickListener(listenerObj);
```